# Set intersection notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm wondering what is the most concise and correct notation for the intersection of the types of sets that come up in inequality problems.
Would both of these be fine or are there better alternatives?

$\begin {cases}x>0\\x<1\\x\ge1 \end {cases} \ \Rightarrow x\in \emptyset\ \hspace{65pt}  x\in(0, \infty)\cap (-\infty,1)\cap[1,\infty)=\emptyset$

Comment: I also would avoid writing $x \in \varnothing$.

Comment: Both of them are logically correct, but it would not be a shame to make a full sentence and to write "there is no solution to the given system of inequalities" !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your question is that the most concise notation is not necessarily the most correct one. I strongly support TheSilverDoe's comment. You could write for instance:

(1) The given system has no solution, since no number $x$ satisfies simultaneously the inequalities $x > 0$, $x < 1$ and $x \geqslant 1$.

or, but I prefer the first one,

(2) As the set $(0, \infty)\cap (-\infty,1)\cap[1,\infty)$ is empty, the system has no solution.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a little sketchy, I think I'd prefer the second. I'd rephrase the first as

$x>0 \ \land \ x<1 \ \land \ x\ge 1$